# Chinese charactors without forefront white space by using regexp?

Tags: regex, preg-match

> **This question is wrong**. The regex serves what I wanted actually. I missed a
>   "*trim()*" before regex checking in the source code.

---

Original Question:

I don't know how. This regexp allow no white space in between Chinese charactors but if you put a whitespace at the front, it would pass.

```
if(preg_match('/^[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}A-Za-z]{1,7}$/u',$username)){
```

As you can see, I want Chinese, English letters, underscore, nothing else.

Comment: I don't have a PHP server to test on tonight, but according to http://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html, your pattern works like you intend: a leading space does not match. Also, you are missing the underscore in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex:

```
/^[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}a-z _]{1,7}$/ui
```

#### Sample code

```php
<?php
    // Since PHP doesn't support Unicode escape sequence, so I use json_decode here for typing random chinese chars
    $username = json_decode('" \u4e00 \u4e01f_o"');
    echo preg_match('/^[\x{4e00}-\x{9fa5}a-z _]{1,7}$/ui',$username); // ouputs 1
?>
```

#### Demo

http://phpfiddle.org/lite/code/c5t-zr2

Comment: Not good enough. White space can appear between Chinese charactors.

Comment: Actually, the forefront white space also still won't pass.

Comment: @Jusfeel I have updated my answer with a demo containing a string with some space, underscore, chinese and english letters. Check the encoding of `$username` in your case. You may need to call `mb_convert_encoding` before using the variable.

Comment: What should the encoding be? I use UTF-8. No go.

Comment: @Jusfeel Check the headers exchanged between the client and the server. You'll see what encoding they have negociated.

Comment: @Jusfeel This time the demo *is* present !

Comment: My bad. My question is wrong. My regex is actually correct. I had a trim inside the code which I missed.